# Filter /Search Custom Post Type Query By Duration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have Created Custom Post Type Named Tours and Different Taxonomies.
I have custom metabox for Tour Duration.
Now, I want to have search Form Filter option .
If I Insert Duration Value Like 14 Days In Metabox, How Can I Query Whether My Custom Metabox Value (Duration) Lies Within My Option Values In Form Like Below and filter Results.
It Should Lies Between 11-15days

```html
<form action="/search-results/" method="post">
<div class="form-group select"> 
<select name="search_duration"> 
<option value="">Any Duration</option> 
<option value="19">1-5 days</option>
<option value="20">6-10 days</option
><option value="21">11-15 days</option>
<option value="22">16-20 days</option>
<option value="36">21-25 days</option>
<option value="37">26-30 days</option>
<option value="39">31-35 days</option> 
</select>
</div><div class="form-group"> 
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Keyword"/></div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="button secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On your search results page you could write a custom loop that uses `meta_query` in it's `$args`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: i have done filter for destination but i wanted to know how to filter duration.

Comment: Are you using a custom loop on the search.php template of where ever you are displaying your search results? If so can you post the code so I can get a better idea of how I can help you.